# Laravel On Demand Notifications not sending emails

Tags: laravel, eloquent, notifications

I have 2 different types of notifications on my web app, one is Notifiable and the other is On Demand Notification.

Notifiable are working fine, but On Demand Notifications are not even sending an error, they pass the try,catch like nothing , it even does not seem to take time to send the form.

Here is my code:

```
 public function sendEmail(Request $request){
        try{
            Notification::route('mail', $request->email)->notify(new propertyData($request->id,$request->email));
            return redirect()->route('opciones.index')->with('success', __('Opción enviada correctamente'));
        }catch(\Exception $e){
            return redirect()->route('opciones.index')->with('danger-modal', __('No se pudo enviar el correo'));
        }
    }
```

Here is my form:

```
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Envío de correo') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                @if (session()->has('success-modal'))
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span class="mdi mdi-close"></span></button>
                        <div class="icon"> <span class="mdi mdi-close-circle-o"></span></div>
                        <div class="message"><strong>{{ __('¡Correcto!') }}</strong> {{ session()->get('success-modal') }}</div>
                    </div>
                @endif
                @if (session()->has('danger-modal'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
                        <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span class="mdi mdi-close"></span></button>
                        <div class="icon"> <span class="mdi mdi-close-circle-o"></span></div>
                        <div class="message"><strong>{{ __('¡Error!') }}</strong> {{ session()->get('danger-modal') }}</div>
                    </div>
                @endif
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('opcion.sendEmail') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{$id}}">

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Email del propietario') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{$opcion->propiedad->propietario->email}}" disabled>
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Enviar') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

Version of Laravel is 7.30.4

PHP version is 7.4.3

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

The problem was that my input field is `disabled` so it's not sending the email to Request, after changing it works fine.

Greetings!